# Is Freestyle this slow?

Tags: performance, freestyle

Rendertime is 1 min 35 seconds with this chair (60 k vertices) occluding the figure.

Without the chair it's .3 seconds of render time

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out freestyle performance is correlated to the amount of vertices, in this case the chair. Simplifying the chair made for better performance